# How to embed old-school (and p,a,c,k,e,d) JavaScript snippet into a React component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to port a Google Translate plugin (gtranslate) popular in the WordPress/Drupal world into a React app. They provide some old-school HTML embed code, but it is p,a,c,k,ed and wrapped in a CDATA, and I'm having trouble calling its main function from my React component. Is there a way to use this code within a React component?

I've tried various variations my non-working code is posted below for reference.

```
    import React from "react";

    const Translate = class extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(event) {
            doGTranslate(this);
        }

      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
            <p>I shall be translated.</p>

              <select onChange={this.handleChange}><option value="">Select Language</option><option value="en|af">Afrikaans</option><option value="en|sq">Albanian</option><option value="en|ar">Arabic</option><option value="en|hy">Armenian</option></select><div id="google_translate_element2"></div>

              <script type="text/javascript">
              {`
              function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}
              `}
              </script>

              /* This is where doGTranslate is defined! */

              <script type="text/javascript">
              {`
              /* <![CDATA[ */
              eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(a,b){n{4(2.9){3 c=2.9("o");c.p(b,f,f);a.q(c)}g{3 c=2.r();a.s(\'t\'+b,c)}}u(e){}}6 h(a){4(a.8)a=a.8;4(a==\'\')v;3 b=a.w(\'|\')[1];3 c;3 d=2.x(\'y\');z(3 i=0;i<d.5;i++)4(d[i].A==\'B-C-D\')c=d[i];4(2.j(\'k\')==E||2.j(\'k\').l.5==0||c.5==0||c.l.5==0){F(6(){h(a)},G)}g{c.8=b;7(c,\'m\');7(c,\'m\')}}',43,43,'||document|var|if|length|function|GTranslateFireEvent|value|createEvent||||||true|else|doGTranslate||getElementById|google_translate_element2|innerHTML|change|try|HTMLEvents|initEvent|dispatchEvent|createEventObject|fireEvent|on|catch|return|split|getElementsByTagName|select|for|className|goog|te|combo|null|setTimeout|500'.split('|'),0,{}))
              /* ]]> */ 
              `}
              </script>
          </>
        )
      }
    }

export default Translate
```

I'm expecting to trigger the `doGTranstlate` function called from my event handler on the onChange from my SELECT list.

Instead I am getting `doGTranslate is undefined`. The `doGTranslate` function itself appears to be embedded within the p,a,c,k,e,d portion of the script.

NOTE: If I change my event handler to an alert() or a console.log() it works fine, I just can't get it to trigger this embedded function.

Comment: I think you can take those two <script> blocks and move them into the <head> of your index.html file, then you should be OK...

Comment: thanks @MattHolland I've tried that, and it only kind of solves -- when I place all of the scripts in the <head> and I can get a working translation BUT it causes a secondary SELECT list in to appear in the header, and the SELECT list I actually want to use mimics the ghost SELECT list but is not actually functional (i.e. i  cannot simply hide the ghost SELECT list.)

According to their DOCs it seems that those embedded scripts need to appear after the SELECT for some reason, and even the Drupal and WordPress versions of this output that code directly inline, so I'm not sure. But thank you!

Comment: Just a note that I tried some more experiments with <head> and also trying place the code in the footer with no luck. I also verified that in the Drupal version, it does in fact place these two scripts inline, instead of in <head>, which is an anti-pattern, because virtually all Drupal integrations place the script(s) into <head>. so I'm assuming it is for a reason. FWIW this the plugin I'm trying to port (see the HTML tab): https://gtranslate.net/download

Comment: Yeah, sounds like the script is very specific about where it is loaded!

Comment: One other idea is to maybe try adding it via JavaScript in one of the React lifecycle methods: e.g. `componentDidMount`, like: `componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = /* your script's code */
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
`

Comment: At this point, I'm mostly positive this has something to do with how the script is eval(p,a,c,k,e,d) and obfuscated, and that React cannot correctly unpack. When I add this portion of the script to componentDidMount, it tries to parse the script and fails with many syntax errors (e.g `parseint` vs `parseInt` or `fromcharcode` vs `fromCharCode`.) When I attempt to manually fix the case issues, I start to get other errors such as `SyntaxError: Unexpected token else`. 

I would be very happy to hear of anybody else out there who has integrated this kind of script successfully!

Comment: Also, for the record I've tried various methods of "unpacking" the script (via online tools) but it seems to be tightly packed and fools all of the converters I've tried.